# Pylance Type Checking Issues with Multiple Azure SDK API Versions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance, azure-sdk-python

I'm working on a Python project that uses the Azure SDK, and I'm encountering type checking issues with VS Code/Pylance due to the multi-API versioning mechanism of the Azure SDK.

Here's the error message I'm receiving from Pylance:

```
Expression of type "azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_04_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_07_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_11_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_08_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_11_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_07_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2016_03_30.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2016_04_30_preview.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_03_30.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_04_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_06_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_10_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine" cannot be assigned to declared type "VirtualMachine"
  Type "azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_04_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_07_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_11_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_08_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_11_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_07_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2016_03_30.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2016_04_30_preview.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_03_30.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_04_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_06_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2018_10_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine | azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine" cannot be assigned to type "VirtualMachine"
    "azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_03_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine" is incompatible with "azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine"
```

I'm looking for a way to suppress these errors without losing the benefits of type checking.

Here's a simplified example of how I'm using the Azure SDK in my code:

```py
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute.models import VirtualMachine

[...]

def get_virtual_machine_details(
        self, resource_group_name: str, vm_name: str
    ) -> VirtualMachine:
    vm_details = self._compute_client.virtual_machines.get(
            resource_group_name, vm_name, expand="instanceView"
        )
    return vm_details
```

This is an example with the VirtualMachine type but it happens with ResourceGroup and others...
It does not happen when I use Pycharm instead of VS Code.

I used a lot of **# type: ignore** in my code, it works, but I feel it's not the most elegant solution.

Comment: Hello, I'm the manager at Microsoft of the Azure SDK for Python, can you open an issue on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues , so I can put my Typing expert on the problem. Thanks!